# Geometric interpretation of random effects design matrix

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, geometry

A fixed effects (FE) linear model can be understood in a precise way using concepts of geometry. Namely, the response vector in model space is projected onto the design subspace surface described by the fixed effects design matrix. In this geometrical interpretation of a fixed effect model, each column in the FE design matrix can be considered as a vector in model space, and each row in the FE design matrix can be considered as a basis vector in design space.

I am curious if there is a similar geometrical interpretation for random effects (RE) linear models. So far, I understand that the model fitting procedure for RE linear models uses a different coefficient discovery procedure, called penalized least squares, which does not give a clean interpretation of the RE design matrix coefficients due to weighting of the coefficients.

Does this mean that no geometric interpretation is possible?